# AWS Kinesis Stream - each record is related to different log group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I created AWS Kinesis stream. 
several different EKS log groups destination point to the same Kinesis stream.

i didn't find any documentation that make sure that each record i get is related to **ONLY** one log group and it doesn't include logs from different log groups.

I would like to make sure that its the way its works.

Anyone know?

Comment: If you want an answer, you will have to be more explicit about how the log messages are being written to a stream. It looks like you've subscribed a CloudWatch Logs stream to Kinesis. Is this correct? Or are you using some other package, like Fluent?